# ReactDOM.render issue

Tags: reactjs, react-dom

having an odd error with ReactDOM.render

in my ListItem component i have 2 functions which call ReactDom.render:

```
    showDetails()
    {
        var popup = document.getElementById("itemPopup")
        popup.style.display = "block"
        ReactDOM.render(<ItemDetails data={this.props.itemData[1]}/>, popup)
    }
```

and

```
    editItem()
    {
        var popup = document.getElementById("itemPopup")
        popup.style.display = "block"
        ReactDOM.render(
            <EditItem 
                itemID={this.props.itemData[0]}
                itemData={this.props.itemData[1]}
                updateItem={(id, data)=>this.props.itemEdited(id, data)}
        />, popup)
    }
```

showDetails works fine when it is called however editItem shows the first item it's called on regardless of which listItem object calls it.
the only time this changes is when showDetails is called and then the next editItems call shows the right item

thanks in advance for any help in fixing this bug

Comment: who is calling editItem?

Comment: showDetails and editItem are both called by onClick handlers in ListItem

Comment: <Button variant="link" onClick={this.editItem}>...</Button>
<Button variant="link" onClick={this.showDetails}>...</Button

Comment: I don't know the whole context, but for popups that render to a div outside of the tree, you should look into React Portals.

Comment: thanks but the div is in the parent component of ListItem, ViewList

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved the problem by adding

```
ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(popup)
```

just before the reactDOM.render()

full code:

```
    editItem()
    {
        var popup = document.getElementById("itemPopup")
        popup.style.display = "block"
        ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(popup)
        ReactDOM.render(
            <EditItem
                itemID={this.props.itemData[0]}
                itemData={this.props.itemData[1]}
                updateItem={(id, data)=>this.props.itemEdited(id, data)}
        />, popup)
    }
```